# Copy the range and check for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

Dears, 
I would like to add to the below code, the lines, which do the following:

1. Copy the range from Results tab and pastes it to every newly created sheet. It should be copied to the same column which is populated by the below macro.

I think we would need to add this code somewhere:

```
Worksheets("Results").Range("A1:A65").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("a50:a150") ???
```

2. It should also check this column for duplicates.

Will you ba able to help?

the initial code is the following:

```
Sub YouShouldHavePostedAnAttemptFirst()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim CtRows, SheetCtr As Integer
    'Try to put your data on sheet 1 then create a new sheet so that it is the
    'second sheet in the workbook.

    SheetCtr = 4

    CtRows = Application.CountA(Sheets("2nd step").Range("r:r"))

    For Each c In Range(Cells(1, 18), Cells(CtRows, 18))
        c.Offset(, -10).Copy Sheets(SheetCtr).Cells(Rows.Count, "a:a").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        If c.Offset(1, 0) <> c Then

            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            SheetCtr = SheetCtr + 1

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Thank you,

Comment: Do the sheets already exist, or are they created as part of the code - in which case how many sheets do you create?  4 - the value of `SheetCtr`?

Comment: 3 of them already exist - the next ones will be created as a part of the code. (in one of the existing is the content to be copied)

Answer (score 1):

This code will copy the data from Results into your existing sheets and then create four new sheets and paste the data in there as well:

```
Sub PopulateSheets()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim SheetCtr As Long, x As Long

    'First go through each sheet in the workbook.
    'If you want other sheets apart from 'Results' to be ignored just add them to the Case.
    'e.g. Case "Results", "Sheet1" will ignore Results & Sheet1.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case wrkSht.Name
            Case "Results"
                'Do nothing - we're copying from this sheet.
            Case Else
                'Copy from Results to the other worksheet.
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
                    .Range("A1:A65").Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A50")
                End With
        End Select
    Next wrkSht

    'Creates 4 sheets, copies the data over and moves the sheet to the end.
    SheetCtr = 4
    With ThisWorkbook
        For x = 1 To SheetCtr
            Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            .Worksheets("Results").Range("A1:A65").Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A50")
            wrkSht.Move After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

**If you just want to copy the data when a new sheet is added -**
In a normal module add the below code.  The procedure takes a reference to a worksheet and copies the data from the Results sheet to it and removes any duplicates.

```
Public Sub CopyToNewSheet(sht As Worksheet)

    With sht
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Range("A1:A65").Copy Destination:=.Range("A50")
        .Range("A50:A114").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With

End Sub
```

In the `ThisWorkbook` module add the below code.  This checks that you're adding a worksheet rather than a chart sheet or any other type and passes the sheet reference to the `CopyToNewSheet` procedure:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Type = xlWorksheet Then
        CopyToNewSheet Sh
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to adjust the code so that it copies the data from "Results" into every newly created sheet? Would this be possible to incorporate this code into my previous already existing code? Apart from this would this check for duplicates? Please let me know if anything is unclear...

Comment: Do you want it to remove duplicates or highlight them?  Are you using Excel 2007+ (will make a difference to the checking for duplicates code).

Comment: I'm not really sure what your original code is trying to do.  This line in your code:  `Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)` will fire the `Workbook_NewSheet` code and copy the data over so it's kind of incorporated into your original code already.

Comment: I would like to highlight them. I am using 2007 version.

Comment: The initial code loops through column "r" and if the value in 'r' changes - it creates a new sheet with the values from the column "r" offset - 10 columns. New sheet is created when the value in column "r" changes.

Comment: i am trying to figure out how to make it working...could you please provide me with a full code that i need to paste in vba explorer? as this is a bit scattered and i got confused:(